# Is there any Hard Drive which helps booting in PC?

Tags: hard-drive

A friend told me that there is a Hard Drive in market which can hold the snap of booting sequence and therefore, always you start your machine it shows desk top in second. Is it really true and if yes, what is the name of such Hard Drive?

Comment: Someone is probably mixing terms. Are you perhaps taking about Microsoft Windows [ReadyBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost) ?

Comment: A lot of Ultrabooks contain a small SSD for the hibernate partition. In case the hibernate feature is used, those computers wake-up very fast. Intel even specifies the maximum number of seconds (don't know the current value) the manufacturers have to undercut.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest hard disk drives are 15,000 RPM. These are rather affordable, but do come in larger sizes for less money than their competition, the Solid State Drive. SSD's usually boot Windows 7 in >30 seconds and Windows 8 in about 10 seconds. There are also hybrids of these that provide small SSD components into a large HDD for speed and storage.

I don't know what it means to snap the boot sequence or why that would speed anything up. BIOS and POST sequences take less than 10 seconds on any HDD so most of the slowness people have is with the operating system load times.

Comment: I hate to nit-pick... but the fasted spindle drives (rate at which they spin) is typically 15000 RPM; not 10K.  This does not make them a great deal faster.  The longest delays during the boot sequence (and most other delays when running applications) comes from the time it takes for the read head to go from one track to the next.  As far as fast booting goes, there are many things you can do.  The simplest of which is to use a SSD, which has no moving parts, and so, almost completely eliminates the "seek time" that all spindle drives suffer from.

Comment: 15K RPM drives were introduced in 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like, your friend does not understand completely what they are talking about. (no offense)

You're looking for the Seagate Momentus XT Hybrid SSD/HDD drives. It has a 4GB/8GB SSD that will cache the most common files used during boot and when running your OS. This will allow your computer to seem like it is booting faster and running some applications faster as it will cache the files onto the SSD which is much faster than the HDD. These drives come in a 500GB and 750GB configuration with a 4GB SSD and 8GB SSD respectively. They do have older drives (640GB model i believe but they only have a 4GB SSD Cache).

Side note: you will never be able to directly access this cache, but can build up a new one by rebooting several times. This is helpful when re-purposing a Momentus XT drive.